# are graphs with fractal dimensions possible?

Tags: fractals

As I am new to understanding fractals, I appreciate their beauty when graphed in cartesian coordinates. My intuitive understanding of the definition of a 'fractal dimension' is the relation of the length of a fractal segment as a proportion of the subdivisions used in making it. In this way. the cartesian 2D coordinate system is calculated to have dimension 2. When we therefore create 2 axes, we can plot a set of points each of which has a real number value in each of these dimensions.

But I imagined a coordinate system not of 2 dimensions, but for example of the dimension of a Koch snowflake, 1.26186. But what does it mean for there to be 1.26186 coordinates for a point? Is this a concept that has been addressed in mathematics? Please do not be hasty to condemn this question as stupid- the concept of the square root of negative one seems equally absurd to me. Yet mathematicians invented a way to deal with that question. And the result was a tool that was miraculous-enabling Fourier transforms and a host of other useful tools-that still want to make my brain explode.

Certainly the concept of length in the fractal dimension has been addressed

[Defining distance in fractal dimensions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157331/defining-distance-in-fractal-dimensions)

So if there is length, then is there not a way to map the fractal coordinate system into the cartesian one so i can visualize it? or would the result be so mind boogling as to exceed comprehensibility- like those drawings of hypercubes in 3 space? We map all the aspects of a hypercube into different 3D cubes and either throw them into a 3D picture together (very messy) or we make a movie of transitioning from one cube to another through time.(very trippy)

Comment: thank you xander. i did search for my question but did not use the proper search terms apparently. Indeed, that is what I was asking. But the answer contained therein was rather complex. I read your exposition through. several times. And of course I had more questions - like this  one -  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409192/fractal-dimensional-analysis?rq=1 .Basically, I am getting the sense that there is no way to graphically represent Hausdorff1.28 D space - where a straight line segment in that space would look like the koch snowflake constructor in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Regarding the ease of finding that post:  I wouldn't have found it if I hadn't known that I had written an answer to it.  That said, I'm not sure how to make it more searchable.  Regarding the linked question, I have starred it with the intention of writing an answer, but have not yet found the time to do so.

Answer (score 0):

When we say $K$ has dimension $1.28$ that simply does *not* mean that a point of $K$ is described by $1.28$ coordinates.

That answers the question, but of course it raises the  second question "Ok, then what *does* it mean?". For an answer to that look on google, especially Wikipedia, for "Hausdorff dimension", "fractal dimension", and various other sorts of dimension that will be mentioned in those articles.